# mostrar todos los datos que tienen un mismo identificador en el mismo registro

Tags: javascript, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy intentando obtener todos los datos vinculados a un mismo id pero que aparezcan en un mismo registro, me explico; tengo dos tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de realizar la siguiente consulta a través de un `inner join`

```
SELECT questions.id_question, questions.title, answers.answer FROM answers INNER JOIN questions ON (answers.question_id = questions.id_question)
```

me muestra la siguiente información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe alguna manera que yo pueda ver todos los datos de un mismo id en el mismo registro, es decir que aparezca una sola vez el `id_question`, el `title` y las `answer` todas en el mismo registro de la siguiente manera?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has intentado con un GROUP BY ??

Comment: al hacer esta consulta: SELECT questions.id_question, questions.title, answers.answer FROM answers INNER JOIN questions ON (answers.question_id = questions.id_question) GROUP BY questions.id_question; solo me trae primer answer de cada id

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del resultado que quieres obtener?

Comment: Vale ya lo hago

Comment: ya mejoré la pregunta

Comment: puedes hacer un `resultado = {};
for (x in data) { 
 if (!resultado[data[x]['id']]) {
  resultado.append({resultado[data[x]['id']]:[]});
 }

 resultado[data[x]['id']][0]=data[x]['title'];
 resultado[data[x]['id']].push(data[x]['answer']); 
}`  al final tendrias lo que deseas y accederias con un `resultado['1'][0]` para el `title` y `resultado['1'][1],resultado['1'][2],resultado['1'][3]` en adelante para las respuestas si quieres el id 2 seria solo hacer `resultado['2'][0]` y listo!

Answer (score 1):

Veo que tienes la etiqueta de javascript en la pregunta, por lo que asumo que realizas una petición y retornas un resultado JSON. Bueno, pues podrías tomar los resultados de la petición y utilizar reduce() para hacer ese agrupamiento que deseas, algo así:

```js
// Asumiento que has obtenido el resultado de la peticiòn y devolviò el siguiente arreglo de objetos
const data = [
    {
        id_question: 1,
        title: '¿cada cuanto recoge la maleza?',
        answer: 'Cada 2 semanas'
    },
    {
        id_question: 2,
        title: 'Otra pregunta',
        answer: 'Otra respuesta'
    },
    {
        id_question: 1,
        title: '¿cada cuanto recoge la maleza?',
        answer: 'Cada 6 semanas'
    },
    {
        id_question: 1,
        title: '¿cada cuanto recoge la maleza?',
        answer: 'Cada 3 semanas'
    },
    {
        id_question: 3,
        title: 'La otra pregunta',
        answer: 'Si'
    },
];

// Agrupamos respuestas por id_question
const respuestas_agrupadas = data.reduce((agrupado, pregunta) => {
    if (!agrupado[pregunta.id_question]) {
        agrupado[pregunta.id_question] = {
            id_question: pregunta.id_question,
            title: pregunta.title,
            answers: []
        };
    }

    agrupado[pregunta.id_question].answers.push(pregunta.answer);

    return agrupado;
}, {});

// Mostramos el agrupamiento
console.log(respuestas_agrupadas);

// Si necesitas un arreglo en vez de un objeto, usas Object.values()
console.log(Object.values(respuestas_agrupadas));
```

Información adicional:

- [Acerca de Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)
- [Acerca de
  Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values)

Comment: si amigo muchas gracias, por responder aunque lo solucione con uno par de for anidados y recorriendo los elementos y almacenandolos en un nuevo objeto pero ya ordenado. Te agradezco por tu colaboración.